# What happens when we do not use return statement in the calling function in C?

Tags: c, return-value

I would like to know the output of the below program. Main concern is what happens when we do not use return statement in the calling function?

```
int sum(int x, int y)
{
    //return x+y; 
}

int main()
{
    int res=0;
    res=sum(1,2);
    printf("res = %d\n",res);
}
```

in the above function `sum()`, if I use `return x+y`; it will print 3 as output?

What happens if I do not use return statement?

Comment: It's undefined behavior. For me, it prints `1`. Anything can happen and there's no guarantee whatsoever. What might happen is that it just takes some random rubbish value on the stack.

Comment: We do not run such programs very often because we use high warning settings with our compilers.

Comment: Which discloses the problem immediately telling the programmer (who is not consciously disregarding the warnings emitted by the compiler) exactly where problem areas in the code lie that should be fixed before proceeding further.

Comment: @n.m. Or maybe we were taught how to create undefined behavior from reading the K&R book, first code example: `main() { printf("hello, world\n"); }`. This was written fom C90 so no implicit return 0...

Comment: @n.m. Nope, it is special now. It wasn't when K&R was written. We have to assume that the caller (OS) might use the return code from the program.

Comment: @Lundin it isn't undefined now, and wasn't undefined in C90. "If the main function executes a return that
specifies no value, the termination status returned to the host
environment is undefined." This is not the same as "undefined behaviour".

Comment: @n.m. It is. Any occurrence of the word "undefined" in the C standard has a special meaning, to point out undefined behavior. Same goes with unspecified and implementation-defined/"defined by the implementation". These are formal terms.

Comment: @Lundin "Any occurrence of the word "undefined" in the C standard has a special meaning, to point out undefined behavior". I'm not sure where you are getting this from.

Comment: @n.m. There's an absence of defined behavior => UB.

Comment: @melpomene I do not subscribe to this interpretation. The intent is obviously different from making the behaviour undefined, otherwise the standard would just use the words "undefined behaviour" like everywhere else. It certainly was not an intent of K&R to make this behaviour undefined, and the standard has codified existing practice. The termination status returned to the host environment is not a part of the abstract C machine description anyway.

Comment: @n.m. The description of `exit` defines the meaning of `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`. Any other value is described as implementation-defined (not "undefined"). I think the authors of the standard intended falling off the end of `main` to have undefined behavior, otherwise they'd have said "unspecified".

Comment: @melpomene "I think the authors of the standard intended falling off the end of main to have undefined behavior". I don't think so. It is utterly irrelevant anyway because the former standard in which the wording appears is superseded by newer standards and is only of historical interest today.

Comment: As others mentioned, it is UB. But, you can try and see what is going to happen and how the result changes from architecture to architecture. For example, I tried a similar example on ARM. Unless there is no modification on the register on which it is used after assignment operator, you can most probably predict the result if you know a bit assembly language and calling convention for this architecture. Please try on: https://godbolt.org

Answer (score 7):

See 6.9.1 (Function definitions) / 12 in [the C11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the same language appears in C99):

> 12. If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

(In C90 there was mostly equivalent language in 6.6.6.4 (The `return` statement):

> If a `return` statement without an expression is executed, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined. Reaching the `}` that terminates a function is equivalent to executing a `return` statement without an expression.

The difference is that (from C99 on) having `return;` with no expression in a non-void function is an error.)

In your case the `}` of `sum` is reached (no `return` statement was executed) and the return value is used:

```
res=sum(1,2);
```

Therefore your code has undefined behavior: Anything can happen, from a garbage value in `res` to an infinite loop or crash.

Comment: I wouldn't say garbage value. It depends on the architecture and how the function call convention is implemented in the compiler. It is UB, but it is not a garbage result at all. Depending on your program, you may predict easily if you know the architecture + compiler etc.

Answer (score 2):

[melpomene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55825810/2445184) is 100% correct from the pure language point of view: Returning from a non-void function without a return value invariably results in undefined behavior. After that, all bets are off.

I'm going to add to this, what is *likely* going to happen:

When you call a function, the compiler has a set of rules that it follows on how the parameters and return value are passed to the callee. These rules are along the lines of "If the first argument is an integral type, put it into register `eax` before invoking the callee". So, if you say `foo(42)`, the compiler emits code to load `42` into the register `eax`, and then to call `foo`, which then just examines the value it finds in register `eax` to know what was passed.

The same happens for the return value. There is a defined place where the caller expects the return value (this may be a register or a memory location on the stack), and it's the callee's obligation to actually put a sensible value there.

So, when you forget to name a return value, **the return value will simply not be set. Whatever happens to be in the respective register / memory location will be *interpreted* as the return value by the caller.** What exactly is effectively "passed back" to the caller depends 100% on how the callee happens to be compiled, and it may be deterministic. Consider this code snippet:

```
int getSecret() {
    return 42;
}

int checkSecret(int guess) {
    int secret = getSecret();
    //return secret == guess;
}

int main() {
    printf("The secret is %d.\n", checkSecret(0));
}
```

If you compile and run this code, you may find that it correct prints the secret value `42`. Why? Simple: When `getSecret()` returns the secret value, it places it where `checkSecret()` expects to find the return value. And this may happen to be the same register as where `main()` expects to find the return value of `checkSecret()`.

From the language perspective, that's perfectly ok: When `checkSecret()` returns without setting a return value, the language allows anything to happen, including leaking the secret. **This is why forgetting the return value can be a security hole**. It may allow an attacker to either extract information that they are not supposed to know, or to trigger code execution paths that are impossible in correct behavior because a function "returns" a value that's not within the expected return value range.